# Formatting of usepackage commands in LaTeX document

Tags: latex, auctex, formatting

I'm trying to use AUCTeX edit LaTeX files. The beginning of the document I just wanted to edit looks like this:

[image]

It's not neatly organized, inconsistent in many ways, and I should probably change it but it's readable. (I didn't pick a nice example, I picked the document I wanted to edit which had parts of it copied in from various other documents which is why it's so inconsistent in the header.)

However, after I selected the entire contents of the document and pressed `C-c C-q C-r` (`LaTeX-fill-region`), it looked like this:

[image]

The rest of the document looked fine before and still looks fine. The header looked ugly before and now looks utterly ravaged.

Is there a way to correct this behavior?

Comment: `hyperref` package should usually be [loaded as the last one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/31416) (and, as every other package, only once).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want a command to stay in a line on its own, add it to [`LaTeX-paragraph-commands`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-LaTeX_002dparagraph_002dcommands):

```lisp
(setq LaTeX-paragraph-commands '("documentclass" "usepackage"))
```

But, honestly, I didn't ever see anyone trying to fill the preamble ;-)

Comment: It was mainly because I misunderstood what filling means.